# How do I show the following identity?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

How do I show that $(x+1)\ln(x+1)>\mathrm{arctan}\;x$, $x$ greater than $0$. Can you give me any idea how to show it?

Answer (score 0):

What happens with both functions (LHS and RHS) at $x=0$?

Then, derivate both, obtaining
\begin{equation}
\ln(x+1) + 1>1
\end{equation}
for the LHS, and
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1+x^2}<1
\end{equation}
for the RHS.

*The inequalities, taking into account that $x> 0$.*

Here you have the plot, where the red graph is the LHS and the green one is $\mathrm{\arctan}\;x$. The black line is $y=x$ (with slope $1$, as you know), so with this you must understand what I mean with the inequalities of the derivatives.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = (x+1)\ln(x+1)$ and $g(x) = \arctan(x)$

Also calculate $$f''(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+1} >0\ \forall\ x>0$$

$$g''(x)=\dfrac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2} < 0 \ \forall \ x > 0$$

Now, we have

$$(f-g)''(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}+\dfrac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2} > 0\ \forall\ x > 0$$

thus $(f-g)'(x)$ is increasing. And as 
 $$(f-g)'(0)=1+(\ln(1))-\dfrac{1}{1+0^2} =0$$

We find that $(f-g)(0) = 0$, so $(f-g)(x) > 0$ for every $x > 0$